# Multi Threading Using Boost C++ - Synchronisation Issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization

I would like to do multithreading where Thread ONE passes data to 4-5 Worker Threads  which process the data and ones ALL Worker Threads are finished I would like to continue. I'm using boost to realize that however I have a synchronisation problem. Meaning at one point the program stops and doesn't continue working.

I used OpenMP before and that works nicely but I would like to set the thread priorities individually and I could not figure out how to do that with OpenMP therefore I worked on my own solution:

I would be very glad if some could give hints to find the bug in this code or could help me to find another approach for the problem.

Thank you,
KmgL

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#define N_CORE 6
#define N_POINTS 10
#define N_RUNS 100000

class Sema{

public:
    Sema(int _n =0): m_count(_n),m_mut(),m_cond(){}

    void set(int _n)
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> w_lock(m_mut);
        m_count = -_n;
    }

    void wait()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mut);
        while (m_count < 0)
        {
            m_cond.wait(lock);
        }
        --m_count;
    }
    void post()
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mut);
        ++m_count;
        m_cond.notify_all();
    }


private:
    boost::condition_variable m_cond;
    boost::mutex m_mut;
    int m_count;

};

class Pool
{
private:
    boost::thread m_WorkerThread;
    boost::condition_variable m_startWork;
    bool m_WorkerRun;
    bool m_InnerRun;
    Sema * m_sem;

    std::vector<int> *m_Ep;
    std::vector<int>  m_ret;

    void calc()
    {
        unsigned int    no_pt(m_Ep->size());                
        std::vector<int> c_ret;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<no_pt;i++)
            c_ret.push_back(100 + m_Ep->at(i));

        m_ret = c_ret;
    }
    void run()
    {
        boost::mutex WaitWorker_MUTEX;
        while(m_WorkerRun)
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> u_lock(WaitWorker_MUTEX);
            m_startWork.wait(u_lock);
            calc();
            m_sem->post();
        }

    }

public:
    Pool():m_WorkerRun(false),m_InnerRun(false){}
    ~Pool(){}
    void start(Sema * _sem){
        m_WorkerRun = true;
        m_sem = _sem;
        m_ret.clear();
        m_WorkerThread = boost::thread(&Pool::run, this);}
    void stop(){m_WorkerRun = false;}
    void join(){m_WorkerThread.join();}

    void newWork(std::vector<int> &Ep)
    {
        m_Ep = &Ep;
        m_startWork.notify_all();
    }
    std::vector<int> getWork(){return m_ret;}



};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Pool TP[N_CORE];

    Sema _sem(0);
    for(int k=0;k<N_CORE;k++)
        TP[k].start(&_sem);


    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));

    std::vector<int> V[N_CORE];

    for(int k=0;k<N_CORE;k++)
        for(int i=0;i<N_POINTS;i++)
        {
            V[k].push_back((k+1)*1000+i);
        }

    for(int j=0;j<N_RUNS;j++)
    {
        _sem.set(N_CORE);
        for(int k=0;k<N_CORE;k++)
        {
            TP[k].newWork(V[k]);
        }

        _sem.wait();

        for(int k=0;k<N_CORE;k++)
        {
            V[k].clear();
            V[k]=TP[k].getWork();
            if(V[k].size()!=N_POINTS)
                std::cout<<"ERROR: "<<"V["<<k<<"].size(): "<<V[k].size()<<std::endl;

        }
       if((j+1)%100==0)
            std::cout<<"LOOP: "<<j+1<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"FINISHED: "<<std::endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race between the calls to `Pool::newWork()` and `Pool::run()`.

You have to remember that signaling/broadcasting a condition variable is not a sticky event.  If your thread is not waiting on the condition variable at the time of the signaling, the signal will be lost.  This is what can happen in your program: There is nothing that prevents your main thread to call `Pool::newWork()` on each of your Pool objects before they have time to call `wait()` on your condition variable.

To solve this, you need to move `boost::mutex WaitWorker_MUTEX` as a class member instead of it being a local variable.  `Pool::newWork()` needs to grab that mutex before doing updates:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> u_lock(WaitWorker_MUTEX);
m_Ep = &Ep;
m_startWork.notify(); // no need to use notify_all()
```

Since you're using a condition variable in `Pool::run()`, you need to handle spurious wakeup.  I would recommend setting m_Ep to NULL when you construct the object and every time  you're done with the work item:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> u_lock(WaitWorker_MUTEX);
while (1) {
    while (m_Ep == NULL && m_workerRun) {
        m_startWork.wait(u_lock);
    }
    if (!m_workerRun) {
        return;
    }
    calc();
    m_sem->post();
    m_Ep = NULL;
}
```

stop() will need to grab the mutex and notify():

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> u_lock(WaitWorker_MUTEX);
m_workRun = false;
m_startWork.notify();
```

These changes should make the 10ms sleep you have un-necessary.  You do not seem to call `Pool::stop()` or `Pool::join()`.  You should change your code to call them.

You'll also get better performance by working on `m_ret` in `Pool::calc()` than copying the result at the end.  You're also doing copies when you return the work.  You might want `Pool::getWork()` to return a const ref to `m_ret`.

I have not run this code so there might be other issues.  It should help you move

It seems from your code that you're probably wondering why condition variables need to go hand in hand with a mutex (because you declare one local mutex in `Pool::run()`).  I hope my fix makes it clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much - I totally missed that race condition. And also thank you a lot for the other suggestions. They were all very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with [Boost futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures). Start the threads then [wait for all](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.wait_for_all) of them to finish. No other synchronization needed.